# Laravel error when sending email notification

Tags: laravel, notifications

- Laravel Version: 8.78.1
- PHP Version: 8.0.10

I've created a custom command to run on a schedule and email a notification.

My Command class handle method:

```
public function handle()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Licences WHERE (Expired = 1)";
    $list = DB::select($sql);

    return (new NotifyExpiredLicences($list))->toMail('me@gmail.com');
}
```

My notification method:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Clients with Expired Licences')
            ->markdown('vendor/notifications/expiredlicences', 
                ['clients' => $this->list, 'toname' => 'Me']);
}
```

Whenever I test this by running it manually with `php artisan email:expired-licences` I get the following error `Object of class Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage could not be converted to int` from my command class in the handle method.

However, the preview of my email works fine & displays as expected:

```
Route::get('/notification', function () {
    return (new SendExpiredLicences())->handle();
});
```

If I remove the `return` statement from my `handle()` method, then although I get no errors, neither in my console or in storage\logs, also the preview stops working.

At this point I'm sure I've missed something important from the way this is supposed to be done, but after going through the Laravel docs and looking at online tutorials/examples, I've no idea what.

Comment: That error also provides a stack trace that tells you **exactly** what line of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: @miken32 - The error occurs in Illuminate/Console/Command.php - fairly certain this is a result of the line `return (new NotifyExpiredLicences....`, but if I change this my preview stops working, I don't get any error, nor an email.

Comment: Yes but the stack trace should give you all the calls preceding the error, so you can find out what is trying to turn the mail into an int. There's nothing in documentation about expected return values from the `handle()` command. Try just taking out `return`?

Comment: Also odd that you aren't using Eloquent models. Anytime I see `DB::select` in code I think there's probably a better way.

Comment: @miken32 - I should have been clearer, by "changing", I meant removing the return statement, means, my preview stops working, I see no errors anywhere and I don't get an email. I'll make my question clearer.

Comment: Using a return from a job handler for display to browser is kind of weird. That’s what controllers are for. Also worth mentioning that nowhere in this code are you actually sending a message. You’re not expecting to get an email are you?

Comment: I've got everything working now, though I'm not convinced it's how it's supposed to be done. I got the preview idea from the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#previewing-mailables-in-the-browser)

Comment: I just find the variable name `$notifiable` confusing, when passing `string` email, because `Notifiable` usually is a `trait` of model `User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got everything working - though not entirely sure it's the "Laravel way".
If anyone's got suggestions for improving it - add a comment or new answer and I'll try it out.

Console\Kernel.php:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) 
{
    $schedule->command('email:expired-licences')
                ->weekdays()
                ->at('08:30');
}
```

App\Console\Commands\SendExpiredLicences.php:

```
class SendExpiredLicences extends Command
{
  protected $signature = 'email:expired-licences';
  protected $description = 'Email a list of expired licences to Admin';
  private $mail;

  public function _construct()
  {
      $clients = DB::select("[Insert SQL here]");
      $this->mail = (new NotifyExpiredLicences($clients))->toMail('admin@example.com');
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    Mail::to('admin@example.com')->send($this->mail);
    return 0;
  }

  public function preview()
  {
    return $this->mail;
  }
}
```

App\Notifications\NotifyExpiredLicences.php:

```
class NotifyExpiredLicences extends Notification
{
    public function __construct(protected $clients)
    {
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new Mailable($this->clients));
    }
}
```

App\Mail\ExpiredLicences.php:

```
class ExpiredLicences extends Mailable
{
  public function __construct(private $clients)
  {
  }

  public function build()
  {
    return $this
            ->subject('Clients with Expired Licences')
            ->markdown('emails/expiredlicences', 
                ['clients' => $this->clients, 'toname' => 'Admin']);
  }
}
```

resources\views\emails\expiredlicences.blade.php:

```
@component('mail::message')

  # Hi {!! $toname !!},

@component('mail::table')
    | Client        | Expired  |
    | ------------- | --------:|
    @foreach ($clients as $client)
    |{!! $client->CompanyName !!} | {!! $client->Expired !!}|
    @endforeach
@endcomponent

<hr />
Thanks, {!! config('app.name') !!}
@endcomponent
```

For previewing with the browser routes\web.php:

```
  Route::get('/notification', function () {
      return (new SendExpiredLicences())->preview();
  });
```

Comment: Typically you don't have a recipient email address in the notification; the code that actually sends the notification will decide where it's going. Ditch the `setup()` method in the console command and just use the constructor to populate a property. See also [constructor promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion)

Comment: And again, using a console command for browser output is wrong.

Comment: @miken32 - updated my answer (didn't know about constructor promotion), not sure how to get rid of the setup method. The browser output is just for dev/testing so I could preview the email without having to send it (as suggested by the docs). Thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty of adjusting your command to use a constructor instead. If this works for you, great! But it is all kind of weird. Like using the notification to get a mail object and then sending that is backward from the usual method of `$user->notify(new SomeNotification());`. But as I say, if it works for you, go for it.

Comment: @miken32 - This is probably were I got confused, all the exmaples/tutorials talk about users, but I just want to run a report on a schedule and email it to a group of people, perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, the original idea was to move all my cron jobs into the Laravel scheduler.

Comment: See this for sending to a specific email address not associated with a user: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications

Comment: @miken32 - I read that but couldn't see how to integrate it, perhaps I shouldn't even have a Notification object at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok just to save more commenting, here's what I'd recommend doing. This is all based on the Laravel docs, but there are multiple ways of doing it, including what you've used above. I don't really think of them as "right and wrong," more "common and uncommon."

Console\Kernel.php: I'd keep this mostly as-is, but [pass the email to the command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) from a [config file](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values), rather than having it fixed in the command.

```php
use App\Console\Commands\SendExpiredLicences;
…
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) 
{
    $recipient = config('myapp.expired.recipient');
    $schedule->command(SendExpiredLicences::class, [$recipient])
        ->weekdays()
        ->at('08:30');
}
```

config/myapp.php:

```php
<?php

return [
    'expired' => [
        'recipient' => 'admin@example.com',
    ],
];
```

App\Console\Commands\SendExpiredLicences.php: update the command to accept the email address as an [argument](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#arguments), use [on-demand notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications), and get rid of `preview()` method. Neither the command or the notification need to know about the client list, so don't build it yet.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Console\Command;
use App\Notifications\NotifyExpiredLicences;
use Illuminate\Support\Facade\Notification;

class SendExpiredLicences extends Command
{
  protected $signature = 'email:expired-licences {recipient}';
  protected $description = 'Email a list of expired licences to the given address';

  public function handle()
  {
      $recip = $this->argument('recipient');
      Notification::route('email', $recip)->notify(new NotifyExpiredLicences());
  }
}
```

App\Notifications\NotifyExpiredLicences.php: the `toMail()` method [should pass the notifiable object](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#formatting-mail-messages) (i.e. the user getting notified) along, because the mailable [will be responsible](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-mailables) for adding the To address before the thing is sent.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Mail\ExpiredLicenses;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NotifyExpiredLicences extends Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new ExpiredLicenses($notifiable));
    }
}
```

App\Mail\ExpiredLicences.php: since the mail message actually needs the list of clients, this is where we build it. We get the recipient here, either from the user's email [or the anonymous object](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#mailables-and-on-demand-notifications).

```php
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\Client;
use Illuminate\Notifications\AnonymousNotifiable;

class ExpiredLicences extends Mailable
{
    private $email;

    public function __construct(private $notifiable)
    {
        // this allows the notification to be sent to normal users
        // not just on-demand
        $this->email = $notifiable instanceof AnonymousNotifiable
            ? $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('mail')
            : $notifiable->email;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        // or whatever your object is
        $clients = Client::whereHas('licenses', fn($q)=>$q->whereExpired(1));

        return $this
            ->subject('Clients with Expired Licences')
            ->markdown(
                'emails.expiredlicences', 
                ['clients' => $clients, 'toname' => $this->notifiable->name ?? 'Admin']
            )
            ->to($this->email);
    }
}
```

For [previewing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#previewing-mail-notifications) with the browser routes\web.php:

```php
Route::get('/notification', function () {
    // create a dummy AnonymousNotifiable object for preview
    $anon = Notification::route('email', 'no@example.com');
    return (new ExpiredLicencesNotification())
        ->toMail($anon);
});
```

Comment: Thanks miken32 - that's a huge help! It's all working now (scheduled, on-demand and preview), I had to make 2 tiny changes to the above code which I'll edit (Kernal.schedule and ExpiredLicences.__construct), not sure I fully understand the ExpiredLicences mailable class, but I can read up on that.